# Extract data from line and add to specific numbered boxes

Tags: python, extract

Sorry, but I need your help if possible. I am a complete beginner in Python and I am completely stuck. I would like to know what would be the first steps to solve my problem.

I have (many pages) of lines with the following structure:

```
pg10_65 * 3.2200  * 22 24 28 30 33 34 36 37

pg10_116 * 3.2420 * 24 28 30 33 34 37

pg10_118 * 3.1500 * 19 24 28 30 33 34 36

pg10_120 * 3.1230 * 24 28 30 33 34 36 37

pg74_32 * 3.0350 * 17 28 30 33 34 36 37 38
```

For each line and in between the `*` symbols I have a value (digit dot four decimals) and after the last `*` symbol I have a series of numbers, from 1 to 68 but not all of them.

I have 68 boxes.

In this example, and for the first line, I want to add `3.2200` to boxes `22, 24, ..., 36, 37`. If there is a 0 add 3.2200 to 0, if there is another value, add to that value.

For the second line, I want to add the values `3.2420` to boxes `24, 28, ..., 34, 37`. If there is a 0 add to 0, if there is another value, add 3.2420 to that value.

And so on for each of the lines.

In the end I would have 60 boxes with all values corresponding to that boxes added.

I am completely stuck on this.

Thanks a lot to everyone for your advice.

José

Comment: What code have you written till now?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution to your problem.

```
def add_to_boxes(input_string, all_boxes):
    '''
    Takes a list of boxes and your string input and does the additions you requested
    '''
    _, float_value, box_list = input_string.split('*')

    float_value = float(float_value) #convert from string to float
    box_list = [int (s) for s in box_list.split(' ')[1:]] #convert from string to list of integers

    print("Adding ", float(float_value), " to ", box_list)
    for box in box_list:
        all_boxes[box-1] += float_value #boxes are numbered from 0 to 67


boxes = [0 for i in range(68)] # 68 boxes with the value 0
input_str = "pg10_65 * 3.2200 * 22 24 28 30 33 34 36 37"

add_to_boxes(input_str, boxes)
print(boxes)
```

Please let me know if you have any questions regarding how it works.